# Why is the browser returning 404 on an existing script?

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404, server-configuration

I have to debug a wordpress site. The backend throws an 404 error on an existing file. (permissions checked, 777 on it did't help)
I can call the url in my browser, the script is shown, but the console still shows the 404 error.

The problem presumably exists since a redesign, where the previous template was copied and edited, but I did not touch the certain files. I can still call the script url from the previous template, it works fine.

The url where the error occurs is: https://sunball-tennis.de/wp-content/themes/sunball%20blue/assets/js/admin.js.php

I'd appreciate any help.

Update 1: 
This is how the script is called: 
`<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.sunball-tennis.de/wp-content/themes/sunball%20blue/assets/js/admin.js.php?ver=5.0.2'></script>`

Update 2: 
The call for the script is generated with this code: 
`wp_register_script('frontact_admin_js', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/assets/js/admin.js.php', array('jquery-ui-resizable', 'jquery-ui-draggable', 'jquery-ui-sortable', 'media-upload', 'thickbox', 'farbtastic', 'jquery-tools-tooltip', 'jquery-uniform'), false, true);`

But as I said: It was exactly the same code and files in the previous template and it also still works when I activate the previous template, but not in the actual one. Driving me nuts.

Comment: Your script look like `javascript` and you are used `php` extension.

Comment: but this is the same with the previous script and that worked. also i don't understand how this is supposed to produce a 404 error?

Comment: Will you please update you question with detail explanation?

Comment: I'm sorry if i'm standing a bit in the tub right now, but please explain which details you need.

Comment: Where you script been used? And how its call in your code etc. Please add piece of code as well.

Comment: allright, sorry, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

All right I've found an answer. In the beginning of the admin.js.php script was a request for wp-blog-header.php which did not work for unknown reasons. Fixed it with adding

`status_header(200);
nocache_headers();`

after the request.
Got the solution from: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/integrating-wp-in-external-php-pages/?replies=22 and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85384/mysterious-http-404-header-in-my-own-scripts

Cheers!